# When does the new testament reference the ark of the covenant or old testament stories that mention it?

Tags: new-testament, ark-of-the-covenant

A large amount of the old testament focuses on the Ark and stories involving it.

- crossing the desert
- crossing the Jordan
- the conquest of the holy land
- the philistine capture of the ark and the destruction of the dragon idol

The new testament includes many references to the old testament, but I can't think of any to the Ark or its role in stories like the above. Where do new testament writers reference it, how do they use the narrative material around it and what do they connect it to?

Comment: Text-search questions are off-topic on this site. Questions are required to quote a scripture reference in order for users to practice hermeneutic analysis. I suggest you consult a concordance which will list the references you seek. We also do not debate or discuss biblical 'topics'. Please see again the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: The only place "Ark of the covenant" is mentioned is in Heb 9:4.

Comment: The Greek word _kiboton_ is mentioned six times and is translated 'ark' (KJV) every time. Four times the reference is to the ark that Noah built ; once is the 'ark of the covenant' Hebrews 9:4 and once is the 'ark of his testament' seen by John in the visions of the Apocalypse, Revelation 11:19. [From Young's Analytical Concordance.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke in the first chapter of his gospel alludes to 2 Samuel 6 and the story of David bringing the ark from the house of Obededom.

*9 And David was afraid of the LORD that day, and said, **How shall the ark of the LORD come to me?***

*16 And as the ark of the LORD came into the city of David, Michal Saul's daughter looked through a window, and saw **king David leaping and dancing before the LORD**; and she despised him in her heart.*

*39 And Mary arose in those days, and went into the hill country with haste, into a city of Juda;
40 And entered into the house of Zacharias, and saluted Elisabeth.
41 And it came to pass, that, when Elisabeth heard the salutation of Mary, **the babe leaped in her womb**; and Elisabeth was filled with the Holy Ghost:
42 And she spake out with a loud voice, and said, Blessed art thou among women, and blessed is the fruit of thy womb.
43 **And whence is this to me, that the mother of my Lord should come to me?**
44 For, lo, as soon as the voice of thy salutation sounded in mine ears, **the babe leaped in my womb for joy**.*

Paul in Romans 3:25 calls Jesus the cover/mercy seat (*hilasterion*, LXX) for our sins.
John in 1st John 2:10 & 4:10 may have the same idea in mind (*hilasmos*).